# How $limit will works with $group in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am having several records in a information table. In which infoId can be common for several users who are involved in that.Information Collection looks like:

```
{
_id:ObjectId(),
infoId:001,
userName:x,
designation:xx,
year:10
},
{
_id:ObjectId(),
infoId:001,
userName:a,
designation:aa,
year:10
},
{
_id:ObjectId(),
infoId:001,
userName:y,
designation:yy,
year:3
},
{
_id:ObjectId(),
infoId:002,
userName:x,
designation:xx,
year:7
},
{
_id:ObjectId(),
infoId:003,
userName:x,
designation:xx,
year:10
},
{
_id:ObjectId(),
infoId:001,
userName:c,
designation:cc,
year:10
}....
```

From the information table, I want to get the records based on grouping infoId. So I can use aggregate query to get this.

```
db.information.aggregate([$group:{_id:$infoId,users:{$push:"$$ROOT"},$sort:{infoId:-1}]);
```

I will get the result like :

```
[{
_id:003,
users:[
    {
    _id:ObjectId(),
    infoId:003,
    userName:x,
    designation:xx,
    year:10
    }]
},
{
 _id:002,
 users:[{
    _id:ObjectId(),
    infoId:002,
    userName:x,
    designation:xx,
    year:7
    }]
},
{
  _id:001,users:[
    {
    _id:ObjectId(),
    infoId:001,
    userName:x,
    designation:xx,
    year:10
    },
    {
    _id:ObjectId(),
    infoId:001,
    userName:a,
    designation:aa,
    year:10
    },
    {
    _id:ObjectId(),
    infoId:001,
    userName:y,
    designation:yy,
    year:3
    },
    {
    _id:ObjectId(),
    infoId:001,
    userName:c,
    designation:cc,
    year:10
    }

]}
```

}]

But in this say I want give some limit in such way that it need to retrieve upto that only.

If I am giving say limit as 4, then it need to return _id:003, _id:002, in _id:001 only two. **Note:**  The limit whatever specifying should not for result after grouping.

**So how can I query this in mongodb?**

Comment: The `$limit`operator for aggregation acts *before* aggregation. So in your case, depending on the order in which the documents are stored in the db, you may have the 4 `_id: 001`, or 3 of them and one `_id: 002`, etc. Is that what you want? I don't really understand your "**Note**" about this issue...

Comment: Limit will work in place, so for example if you have limit at the head of a pipeline it will work as part of the initial query, pre-aggregation, however, if you have the limit within the middle of the pipeline, say after $group, it will limit those grouped documents

Comment: What I meant is, if we give limit in the beginning, it will query the table with match criteria. Consider the record in collection is in order based like infoId value 001,002,003,001,001,001,... I am having sorting too with infoId in descending order. So in this case how defining limit in the beginning will help.

Comment: It will help since this limit will limit the number of documents that get read from disk and sent into the aggregation since this limit works the same way as it would in a normal query.

Comment: Ok. So is it after grouping result will be in order like , [003],[002],[001,001].? Similar way when the query is with ascending order for infoId, then how the result will be?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake in the first comment. So given that, as Sammaye says, if you `$limit`after grouping it limits your grouped docs, then, apart from the order, you would still get `{[003]},{[002]},{[001,001,001,001]}`, because those are only 3 docs, wouldn't you?

Comment: @dgiugg. I don't want limit after group. Because say 1000 records has 001 as infoId, 100 records has 002 as infoId and 300 records has 003 as infoId. I am giving limit as 500 , then what will be the output of the above logic.?